# Highly oscillatory Integral over Airy function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I have to (numerically) integrate this function over all p from  to get a function g(x):

```
f = 0.102354 Exp[(11876.9 p^2 - 
     154.386 p x + (0.000556163 + 0.501713 x) x)]
AiryAi[0.0275599 + 89099. p^2 + 0.00335015 x - 1158.19 p x + 
  3.7638 x^2]
```

I tried this:

```
tabx = Table[{x1, 
    NIntegrate[f /. x -> x1, {p, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
     MinRecursion -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 20]}, {x1, -20000, 1000, 
    100}];
```

However, it takes a long time, I get a lot of error messages and the solution doesn't look like it should, especially for large negative values of x. Is there a clever way to play with methods (or any other way), to make this more accurate and faster?

Comment: Try `Table[{x1, 
  NIntegrate[f /. x -> x1, {p, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory", AccuracyGoal -> 9, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 9, MinRecursion -> 10, 
   MaxRecursion -> 20]}, {x1, -2000, 1000, 100}]`.This results in .

Comment: `{{... ,  {-1600, -2.34539*10^-46}, {-1500, 
  7.44701*10^-163}, {-1400, 0.}, {-1300, 
  5.80957*10^-222}, {-1200, -2.76047*10^-148}, {-1100, \
-2.64119*10^-70}, {-1000, -1.98239*10^-104}, {-900, 
  3.56913*10^-77}, {-800, 0.000755784}, {-700, 1.38624*10^-20}, {-600,
   0.000679051}, {-500, 0.000800901}, {-400, 0.000715841}, {-300, 
  0.000555767}, {-200, 0.000407082}, {-100, 0.000296536}, {0, 
  0.000222761}, {100, 0.000177177}, {200, 0.000152183}, {300, 
  0.000143298}, {400, 0.00014962}, {500, 0.000174703}, {600, 
  0.000229498}, {700, 6.98312*10^-27}, {800, 0.000571349}, ....}`

Comment: thx but that's even worse ;)

Comment: Luke (@does not work.) : Sorry, don't understand you. Can you present the results to compare? TIA and regard,

Comment: I guess the issue is that I evaluated from -20000 to 1000, you somehow lost a 0

Answer (score 3):

1. You should try plotting your functions before assuming they're oscillatory.  Some are not.  Some have numerics issues.
2. You're asking a lot if [you want people to help you with 211 slow integrals](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251060/highly-oscillatory-integral-over-airy-function#comment629155_251060). A MWE should be minimal.

Here's an idea to help with a few of the 211 integrals: Figure out where the support of the integral lies, and make sure it's sampled.

```
rat = Rationalize[Rationalize@#, 0] &;
integrand = Rationalize[rat@f, 0];
min = p /. 
   First@
    Solve[
     D[0.0275599` + 89099.` p^2 + 0.00335015` x - 1158.19` p x + 
         3.7638` x^2 // rat, p] == 0, p];
dp = 1/D[
    0.0275599` + 89099.` p^2 + 0.00335015` x - 1158.19` p x + 
      3.7638` x^2 // rat, p, p];
roots = p /. 
   NSolve[
    SetPrecision[
     0.0275599` + 89099.` p^2 + 0.00335015` x - 1158.19` p x + 
       3.7638` x^2 == 500, 32], p, WorkingPrecision -> 32];
g[x0_ /; -8.180990019212768` < x0 < 1479.8684784944994`] := 
  Block[{x = x0},
   NIntegrate[
    integrand, {p, -Infinity, min - 10 dp, min, min + 10 dp, 
     Infinity}, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", WorkingPrecision -> 16]
   ];
g[x0_] := Block[{x = x0},
   With[{central = 
      NIntegrate[integrand, {p, roots[[1]], Mean@roots, roots[[2]]}, 
       Method -> "LevinRule", WorkingPrecision -> 32, 
       PrecisionGoal -> 6]},
    central +
     NIntegrate[integrand, {p, -Infinity, roots[[1]]}, 
      Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", WorkingPrecision -> 32, 
      PrecisionGoal -> 6, AccuracyGoal -> 16 - Min[Log10@central, 0]] +
     NIntegrate[integrand, {p, roots[[2]], Infinity}, 
      Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", WorkingPrecision -> 16, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 16 - Min[Log10@central, 0]]
    ]];
```

Examples:

```
g[-20000]
(*  1.0286007852287060785130193502038*10^572  *)

g[-2000]
(*  37.208582874780115313397802617944  *)

g[200]
(*  0.0001521828356334408  *)
```